# Will / would usage

Tags: will-would, conditionals

I saw a bloger's post where it was written:

> It looks like he **would** be on the East coast, when I am there.

I wonder if it's correct to use would instead of will? If it's correct what is the rule it is then? Explain it please.

Answer (score 1):

That is a common expression.

> It looks like he would X.

X is a future event, which is probable, but not certain.

Much the same meaning could be conveyed by:

> It looks like he will X.

The "would" from emphasizes the uncertainty, although "it looks like" expresses uncertainty even with "will"

Comment: To me, *when I am here* doesn't look like the future, hence the inconsistency with the first sentence. Admittedly, I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible.

'Look like' is used to express possibility. (a situation seems like)

It looks like rain.= It looks as if/as though it is going to rain.

We usually use a clause after 'as if' or 'as though'. After the preposition 'like' we can use a noun or an adjective rather than a clause. But in informal English, especially in American English 'like' can be used instead of 'as if' or 'as though'.

It looks like it is going to rain.